# I want to filter to show orders that their ending date is today

Tags: datetime, input-formats

I am using Drupal 7 and I have a webform where people can order a product and they enter the date that they will pick up that product. I want to make a view that will show me the poeple that are picking a product today, but when I try to make a filter for that the fields that are given are only the date that they submited the order not the date_field. Here is a picture of which fields are given to select.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use webform fields in views filter/sort, you will need to add relationship with them. They should be available for relationship in the format or `Webform submissions: Data :XXX`.

Once you add them, you can further use them in filter/sort with more conditions. Hope it helps !!